# My footer div won't connect to the left side of page and other divs collapse

Tags: html, css

I've been racking my brains to to figure out where I went wrong. The bottom div stretches all the way right will everything stays center page but the left side won't stretch full. Also when I resize the window smaller all the sub-divs collapse. Ideas???

https://jsfiddle.net/g506gk51/

Thank you in advance!

```css
 <style type="text/css">

    * {
        font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
    }


    body {
        background-color: white ;
        color: #543864 ;
  z-index: -10;
  clear: both;
    }

    #topmenu {
        float: left;
        padding-top: 50px;
        position: relative;

 }

    #topmenu ul {
         list-style:none;
        
    }

    #topmenu li {
        float:left;
        padding: 5px 30px 0px 20px;
        margin-right: 20px; 
        border-right: 1px solid #292E37;
        text-decoration: underline;

    }

    a:hover {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    a:link {
        color: #292E37;
    }


    #name {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: #543864;
        display:inline-block;

    }

    #topcontainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 15%;
        font-family: Lucida Grande;
        margin-right: 50px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  

    }

        

 
     
     #footer {
         
        background-color:#B9B7C4;  
  height: 11%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
   
     }

     #wrapper {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      width: 960px;
 
     }

     #Header {

         float:left;
   padding-left: 75px;

     }


       
  .circlefooter {
 
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
   margin: 25px 25px 0 175px;
   
   
  }

  .circlefooter p {
 
   padding-left: 75px;
   width: 150px;
   font-size: 12px;
   
   
  }
  
  .circlefooter img {
   
  height: 50px;  
  float: left;
  }
  
  .circlefooter a:hover {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  
 

 </style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>About</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

 


</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="topcontainer">

    <div id ="Header">
        <h1 id="name">Johnny</h1>
        <br />
        Software QA | Software Developer <br />
        Six Sigma Black Belt | Veteran <br />
        Entrepreneur
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="topmenu">
        
            <ul>
                <li><a href="PersonalPageResume.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="PersonalPageResume.html">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="PersonalPageProtfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="PersonalPageContact.html">Contact</a></li>
               
            </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div id="break"></div>-->
    

   
    
    <div id="footer">
    
           <div class="circlefooter" >
      <img  src="http://i107.photobucket.com/albums/m316/sysofadown3/1430028867_MB__phone_zps8zdslqey.png" />
     
      <p >Cell: <br/> 123-456-7890</p>
  
     
     </div>

                    

                    <div class="circlefooter" >
      <img src="http://i107.photobucket.com/albums/m316/sysofadown3/1430028672_18_email-128_zps9hghdji6.png"/>
      <p>Email: <br/> <a href="mailto:ert@dev.com">test@domain.com</a></p>
  
     </div>

                    

                    <div class="circlefooter">
      <img src="http://i107.photobucket.com/albums/m316/sysofadown3/1430028664_06_linkedin-128_zpsd5onsu1x.png"/>
      
      
     </div>
    
    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand what you meant, I got this from your code.

```css
* {
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
    background-color: white ;
    color: #543864 ;
    z-index: -10;
    clear: both;
}
#topmenu {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
#topmenu ul {
    list-style:none;
}
#topmenu li {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 30px 0px 20px;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    border-right: 1px solid #292E37;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    font-size: 20px;
}
a:link {
    color: #292E37;
}
#name {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #543864;
    display:inline-block;
}
#topcontainer {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
#topcontainer:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
#footer {
    background-color:#B9B7C4;  
    height: 11%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
#header {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.circlefooter {
    display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.circlefooter p {
  margin: 0;
    padding-left: 75px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.circlefooter img {
    height: 50px;    
    float: left;
}
.circlefooter a:hover {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>About</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="topcontainer">
            <div id ="header">
                <h1 id="name">Johnny</h1>
                <br />
                Software QA | Software Developer <br />
                Six Sigma Black Belt | Veteran <br />
                Entrepreneur
            </div>
            <div id="topmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="PersonalPageResume.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PersonalPageResume.html">Resume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PersonalPageProtfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PersonalPageContact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div id="break"></div>-->
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="circlefooter" >
                <img  src="http://i107.photobucket.com/albums/m316/sysofadown3/1430028867_MB__phone_zps8zdslqey.png" />
                <p >Cell: <br/> 123-456-7890</p>
            </div>
            <div class="circlefooter" >
                <img src="http://i107.photobucket.com/albums/m316/sysofadown3/1430028672_18_email-128_zps9hghdji6.png"/>
                <p>Email: <br/> <a href="mailto:ert@dev.com">test@domain.com</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="circlefooter">
                <img src="http://i107.photobucket.com/albums/m316/sysofadown3/1430028664_06_linkedin-128_zpsd5onsu1x.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```